# What is the proper setup.py configuration for PyPI Packages with man pages and icons?

Tags: python, icons, python-3.7, setuptools, manpage

I have a working setup.py file and the man pages and icon files are available after pip installing from PyPI, but I just noticed that the parameter `data_files` is deprecated.  Here is my current setup.py file contents:

```
with open(os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent, 'README.md'), 'r') as file_ptr:
    long_description = file_ptr.read()

setup(name='rickslab-gpu-utils',
      version=__version__,
      description='Ricks-Lab GPU Utilities',
      long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
      long_description=long_description,
      author='RueiKe',
      platforms='posix',
      url='https://github.com/Ricks-Lab/gpu-utils',
      packages=['GPUmodules'],
      include_package_data=True,
      scripts=['gpu-chk', 'gpu-ls', 'gpu-mon', 'gpu-pac', 'gpu-plot'],
      license='GPL-3',
      python_requires='>=3.6',
      project_urls={'Bug Tracker':   'https://github.com/Ricks-Lab/gpu-utils/issues',
                    'Documentation': 'https://github.com/Ricks-Lab/gpu-utils/blob/master/docs/USER_GUIDE.md',
                    'Source Code':   'https://github.com/Ricks-Lab/gpu-utils'},
      classifiers=[__status__,
                   'Operating System :: POSIX',
                   'Natural Language :: English',
                   'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
                   'Topic :: System :: Monitoring',
                   'Environment :: GPU',
                   'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)'],
      install_requires=['cycler>=0.10.0',
                        'kiwisolver>=1.1.0',
                        'matplotlib>=3.1.3',
                        'numpy>=1.18.1',
                        'pandas>=1.0.1',
                        'pyparsing>=2.4.6',
                        'python-dateutil>=2.8.1',
                        'pytz>=2019.3',
                        'ruamel.yaml==0.16.10',
                        'ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.0',
                        'six>=1.11.0'],
      data_files=[('share/rickslab-gpu-utils/icons', ['icons/gpu-mon.icon.png',
                                                      'icons/gpu-pac.icon.png',
                                                      'icons/gpu-plot.icon.png']),
                  ('share/rickslab-gpu-utils/doc', ['README.md', 'LICENSE']),
                  ('share/man/man1', ['man/gpu-chk.1',
                                      'man/gpu-ls.1',
                                      'man/gpu-mon.1',
                                      'man/gpu-pac.1',
                                      'man/gpu-plot.1'])
                  ]
      )
```

What is the preferred alternative to using `data_files`?  Or is it safe to continue to use it?  I read that it no longer works with twine, but this definitely works with the latest twine on python3.7.

Comment: `pip` is a tool to install Python **libraries** from PyPI, not **applications**. The fact it's possible to install applications is a side-effect of possibility to install scripts accompanying libraries. For applications you should create proper installers. Think for example about a user who installs your application into a virtualenv; where should the icons go?

Comment: @phd  Thanks for your feedback.  Based on limited experience working on a past debian package, I thought setuptools are also used for the creating of a debian installer.  I will have to do some additional research, but the simplicity of using PyPI is very appealing.